# FIT BROWSER: Image RESIZE

Tags: html, css

I am struggling hard to make the images resize to fit the browser just like the background-image using.

However, the images do not resize to fit the screen and i tried to adjust the size of the browser. The images would go everywhere. I want the images to stay on the same spot when ever resizing occur. Any ideas on what i might have missed?

```css
body{
  background: url(https://wallpapersultra.net/wp-content/uploads/8K-HD-Sunset-Pictures-588x315.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size: 100%;

}
.boat2{
  width: 400px;
  position:absolute; bottom: 160px; left: 800px;z-index: 1;

}
.cabbage{
  width: 150px;
position:absolute; bottom: 290px; right: 290px;z-index: 1;
}
.sheep{
  width: 150px;
  position:absolute; bottom: 300px; right: 180px;z-index: 1;
}
.wolf{
  width: 300px;
  position:absolute; bottom: 270px; right: -80px;z-index: 1;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
 height:auto;
 max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title>IQ River Crossing</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="image">
<img class="boat2"src="http://wallpaperlatest.com/wp-content/uploads/biker-destination-hd-wallpaper-latest.jpg" alt="">
<img class="cabbage" src="http://wallpaperlatest.com/wp-content/uploads/cool-latest-hd-wallpaper.jpg" alt="">
<img class="sheep" src="http://wallpaperlatest.com/wp-content/uploads/floating-island-latest-wallpaper-hd.jpg" alt="">
<img class="wolf" src="http://wallpaperlatest.com/wp-content/uploads/high-definition-latest-wallpaper.jpg" alt="">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can only see one image in the snippet, or am I wrong?

Comment: Just a min @Swellar let me edit my code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function set_body_height() { // set body height = window height
    $('body').height($(window).height());
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind('resize', set_body_height);
    set_body_height();
  });
```

```css
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .fit { /* set relative picture size */
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
  .center {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<img class="center fit" src="http://minisoft.com.bd/uploads/ourteam/rafiq.jpg" >    

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried using @Rafiqul Islam it worked out..! Thanks much